# Django/rest show nested object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My user serializer:

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        read_only_fields = ('email', )
```

Current response:

```
{
    "username": "django",
    "email": "email@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "bim",
    "last_name": "bem"
}
```

I would like to make it respond nested with "user" as a key, like this:

```
{user:
    {
    "username": "django",
    "email": "email@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "bim",
    "last_name": "bem"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can create your own dictionary from the one that is returned from the serializer and serve it.

Something like this:

```
serializer = UserDetailsSerializer(somedata)
serialized_data = serializer.data
jsondata = JSONRenderer().render({'user': serialized_data })
```